# Sabre- Bargain Finder Max Rest API - Frequent flyer - PassengerDataType

Tags: rest, implementation, sabre

I am working on implementing the Sabre Bargain Finder Max Rest API and am trying to create a shop RQ for one-way sector fare flights on QF with specific frequent flyer information.

```
`TravelPreferences.TPA_Extensions.NDCIndicators.FrequentFlyer[]
{"AccountNumber": "0000000",
"AirlineDesignator": "QF",
"PassengerId": "ADT1"}`
```

I get an error:

```
PassengerId from NDCIndicators not found in passengers' definitions
```

Further digging into the document I came across "PassengerDataType"
[Screenshot from the reference document](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mv78A.png)
This seems to be where I can define the passengerID however where in the request am I supposed to input this?

Please help!!!

No idea what to try and what to expect. I am not a developer!